# How to split rows of 1 column into other columns?

Tags: google-spreadsheets

How to transform this :

```
Color   Number  Fuit

Yellow
1
Banana
Red
2
Apple
Green
3
Grape
```

...into this :

```
 Color   Number  Fuit
    
Yellow    1    Banana
Red       2    Apple
Green     3    Grape
```

My best try was to use =split(C22,char(10)&","), but it just split every line in a new column. They should be splited into new columns until a certain number of time, in this case, 3 times. And them jump to the row bellow. And so on.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like the following:
`=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,A2:A),"(([\w\s\S]+?,){3})","$1@"),"@")),",")))`
As detailed in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/65624161/5518385

---

Another similar method is:
`=ArrayFormula(TRIM(split(transpose(SPLIT(Query(A2:A10&","&if(MOD(row(A2:A10)-row(A1),3)=0,"|",""),,9^9),"|")),",")))`
As detailed in this post https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/split-a-column-into-multiple-n-columns-sheets/